# What key is used by openssl (command) for HMAC if key is not passed in as argument

Tags: java, openssl, hmac

I am writing a program using Java to generate HMAC for given String using javax.crypto.Mac.

But in order to troubleshoot and experiment, I use openssl dgst to generate HAMC (using SHA256). I have observed that the command successfully executes even if the key is not passed. For example,

standard way of generating HMAC using openssl on shell,

```
echo -n "data" | opnessl dgst -sha256 -hmac "KEY1"
```

However I can execute following as well,

```
echo -n "data" | opnessl dgst -sha256 -hmac
```

and both commands run successfully with different output.

I assume the non-existence of key can be perceived by openssl as '\0' (null) key.

Actually my problem is I am unable to generate similar results using javax.crypto.Mac and providing SecretKey with byte[0] = 0; (single byte key having 0 as value).

Comment: A bug report was filed on the documentation. See [Bug 3504](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3504) in OpenSSL's RT. The username and password are "guest", if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: According to Rich Salz on the OpenSSSL mailing list, the key is *not* optional with the `-hmac` option. Expect the behavior of the `openssl dgst` command to change in the future.

The change will probably occur with OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1.0. It may be back ported to lesser version like 1.0.1, but there are no guarantees.

---

> Actually my problem is I am unable to generate similar results using javax.crypto.Mac and providing SecretKey with byte[0] = 0;

Just use a SHA-256 hash, and not an HMAC. If this is TLDR; then jump to the end ;)

The source file of interest is `<openssl src>/apps/dgst.c`. Line 225 is where the key is (or should be) set, but its not because there's no following argument:

```
else if (!strcmp(*argv,"-hmac"))
{
    if (--argc < 1)
        break;
    hmac_key=*++argv;
}
```

---

> What key is used by openssl (command) for HMAC if key is not passed in as argument

To answer this question, we need to look at the source in `<openssl src>/apps/dgst.c`.

The `-hamc` switch populates variable `hmac_key`, but its `NULL` so its skipped. The other variable of interest is `sigkey`, buts its also `NULL` so its skipped, too.

Line 513 or so is where things get interesting. Nearly everything else is skipped in `dgst.c` (from under `lldb`):

```
   513      if (argc == 0)
   514      {
-> 515          BIO_set_fp(in,stdin,BIO_NOCLOSE);
   516          err=do_fp(out, buf,inp,separator, out_bin, sigkey, sigbuf,
   517                    siglen,NULL,NULL,"stdin",bmd);
   518      }
(lldb) p sigkey
(EVP_PKEY *) $25 = 0x0000000000000000
```

So all we need to do is look at `do_fp`, and its shown below. The line of interest is 627, where this is executed:

```
len=BIO_gets(bp,(char *)buf,BUFSIZE);
```

The `BIO bp` is a chain, and its got your hash chained to it. So whatever you put into it gets hashed. And the hash is not keyed because `hmac_key` and `sigkey` were `NULL`.

At line 654, this is encountered:

```
BIO_printf(out, "(%s)= ", file);
```

At lines 655 - 660, the loop that performs hex encoding is encountered.

Combined, they produce something like:

```
(stdin)= 6667b2d1aab6a00caa5aee5af8ad9f1465e567abf1c209d15727d57b3e8f6e5f
```

---

```
int do_fp(BIO *out, unsigned char *buf, BIO *bp, int sep, int binout,
          EVP_PKEY *key, unsigned char *sigin, int siglen,
          const char *sig_name, const char *md_name,
          const char *file,BIO *bmd)
{
    size_t len;
    int i;

    for (;;)
    {
        i=BIO_read(bp,(char *)buf,BUFSIZE);
        if(i < 0)
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "Read Error in %s\n",file);
            ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
            return 1;
        }
        if (i == 0) break;
    }
    if(sigin)
    {
        EVP_MD_CTX *ctx;
        BIO_get_md_ctx(bp, &ctx);
        i = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, sigin, (unsigned int)siglen);
        if(i > 0)
            BIO_printf(out, "Verified OK\n");
        else if(i == 0)
        {
            BIO_printf(out, "Verification Failure\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error Verifying Data\n");
            ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    if(key)
    {
        EVP_MD_CTX *ctx;
        BIO_get_md_ctx(bp, &ctx);
        len = BUFSIZE;
        if(!EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, buf, &len))
        {
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "Error Signing Data\n");
            ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        len=BIO_gets(bp,(char *)buf,BUFSIZE);
        if ((int)len <0)
        {
            ERR_print_errors(bio_err);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if(binout) BIO_write(out, buf, len);
    else if (sep == 2)
    {
        for (i=0; i<(int)len; i++)
            BIO_printf(out, "%02x",buf[i]);
        BIO_printf(out, " *%s\n", file);
    }
    else
    {
        if (sig_name)
        {
            BIO_puts(out, sig_name);
            if (md_name)
                BIO_printf(out, "-%s", md_name);
            BIO_printf(out, "(%s)= ", file);
        }
        else if (md_name)
            BIO_printf(out, "%s(%s)= ", md_name, file);
        else
            BIO_printf(out, "(%s)= ", file);
        for (i=0; i<(int)len; i++)
        {
            if (sep && (i != 0))
                BIO_printf(out, ":");
            BIO_printf(out, "%02x",buf[i]);
        }
        BIO_printf(out, "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you want to step it yourself, then download and unpack the OpenSSL sources. Then, configure with a debug build:

```
cd openssl-1.0.1h
./Configure debug-darwin64-x86_64-cc no-ssl2 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
make depend && make
```

Open it up under a debugger:

```
cd openssl-1.0.1h
lldb apps/openssl
```

And finally run it:

```
(lldb) b dgst.c:513
(lldb) r dgst -sha256 -hmac
```

The debugger should snap near `do_fp`:

```
Process 27371 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x286a3, 0x000000010000ba99 openssl`dgst_main(argc=0, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa60) + 5961 at dgst.c:513, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000010000ba99 openssl`dgst_main(argc=0, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa60) + 5961 at dgst.c:513
   512      
-> 513      if (argc == 0)
   514      {
   515          BIO_set_fp(in,stdin,BIO_NOCLOSE);
   516          err=do_fp(out, buf,inp,separator, out_bin, sigkey, sigbuf,
(lldb)
```

The trick is: when you enter `do_fp`, the program will start reading from `stdin`. Enter your string (i.e., `data`) and then do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to EOF it.

---

Now, after all of that, here's the short answer :)

```
$ echo -n "data" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac
(stdin)= 3a6eb0790f39ac87c94f3856b2dd2c5d110e6811602261a9a923d3bb23adc8b7
$ echo -n "data" | openssl dgst -sha256 
(stdin)= 3a6eb0790f39ac87c94f3856b2dd2c5d110e6811602261a9a923d3bb23adc8b7
```

Comment: Wish could I upvote twice. Thanks @jww, you really solved the issue.